# How to close modal in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-modal

I have a react modal, which inside a body contains a button, on clicking this button it opens new page eg payment page but the modal still open, now I want on the click it should open a new page and close the modal.

Here is my modal

```
function ModalA() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        dispatch(actions.modalsActions.closeModal({
            id: "ModalA",
        }))
    }
    return (
       <Modal id="ModalA">

          <button onClick={}>Upgrade Now</button>

       </Modal>
    )
}

export default ModalA
```

Now when I click the Upgrade now button it open a new page but it does not close the modal.

Is there any good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to call both functions inside the onClick. The below code should work

```
<button onClick={() =>{
    handleCloseModal()
    history.push('/account/payments')   
}}>Upgrade Now</button>
```

Comment: Hej I am doing that did u check my modal?